# 3DS Max - How to install plugins with the .dlm extension?

Tags: 3ds-max, plugins

Hello GraphicsDesign community!
This will be my first question here and it's probably a noob question, but...

How do I install 3DS Max (2015) plugins with the .dlm extension?

Most of the guides for installing plugins I found online instruct to drop the file at one of the plugins folders on 3DS's installation directory (Usually at C:\Program Files\Autodesk\3ds Max 2015\plugins), and then the plugin will be visible inside 3DS Max's Plugin Manager list, where it can be activated.

But I am trying to install the [Clone modifier plugin](http://www.itoosoft.com/freeplugins/clone.php), for which the install instructions say the same, but I can't see the plugin in the Manager's list...

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep...It was a noob question...

All I had to do was restart 3DS Max, but of course none of the guides ever stated this...

:|